# Generic Zariski density after reduction mod p

Tags: algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a simple algebraic group over $R:=\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{N}]((t))$. Let  $\rho:\Gamma\to G(R)$ be a representation where $\Gamma$ is a finitely generated  group. Then $\rho$ induces a representation $\rho':\Gamma\to G\big(\mathbb{Q}((t))\big)$. Assume that   $\rho'$  is Zariski dense. Note that $R\subset \mathbb{Z}_p((t))$ for every prime $p\nmid N$, and thus there is a natural morphism $R\to \mathbb{F}_p((t))$. Then $\rho$ also induces a representation   $\rho_p: \Gamma\to G\big(\mathbb{F}_p((t))\big)$.

Question: does there exist large $N'\in \mathbb{N}$ so that    $\rho_p: \Gamma\to G\big(\mathbb{F}_p((t))\big)$ is Zariski dense for every $p\nmid N'$?